# Defining static class pointer within another class

Tags: c++, class, variables, static

I have a class that has a static pointer to another class, which is a singleton. The problem that I seem to be getting though is that I cannot set the pointer from within the constructor of said class. Here is my current code:

```
class B;

class A
{
  public:
    A();
    ~A();
};


class B
{
  public:

    B();
    ~B();

    static A* a;
};

A::A() {
  A* B::a = this;
}
```

Now, the problem that I seem to be getting is that I cannot define B::a in the "current scope". In addition, the "this" pointer can only be used in a "nonstatic member function".

I think the problem has to do with defining the static class variable within another class function, but I am not sure.

Comment: So you want a static member that can be used before the class is instantiated to not be defined until another class is instantiated?

Comment: What are you asking? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Since `B::a` is public (in addition to being static), you can do `B::a = this;` in the constructor of `A`. But the effect will be that 1) `B::a` won't be initialised until the first intance of `A` is created, and 2) Every time a new instance of `A` is created, `B::a` will change. Are you sure that is what you want? It sounds extremely unusual.

Comment: A is a singleton class, meaning it will only be constructed once. It will also be constructed in the beginning of the program, so virtually nothing occurs prior to it.

Comment: Ok. I would find it a lot more intuitive if `B::a` was assigned its value in the same place where the one-and-only instance of `A` is created, rather than from inside `A`'s constructor, but it's certainly possible. The key problem in your code is not the assignment `B::a = this`, but the fact that there is `A *` in front of it, which makes it a declaration, rather than an assignment.

Comment: Yeah. I thought that that was necessary from other relevant questions, but I didn't know that it had to be separate from the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, static class members have to be defined as well as declared. `static A* a;` in the body of class B is merely a declaration, and you need to **define** a. Note that every class member must have a single definition, that's why we usually define static members in the appropriate `.cpp` files for classes. Obviously, this happens outside of the class body. You also cannot define a static member in scope of a function.

So, move the definition of a outside of the constructor's scope, like this:

```
class B
{
public:

    B();
    ~B();

    static A* a;};

A* B::a = 0; // Good idea to set a default value for the pointer
```

Note, however, that the value of `a` will contain a 0 until at least one object of type A is created.

Comment: Okay, I get it. I didn't know you had to define the static variable twice.

Comment: Note that you actually *define* a static variable only once. The answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration will help you better understand the difference between declaration and definition :)

Answer (score 0):

You should define all static members outside the class declaration:

```
class B;
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
};


class B
{
public:

    B();
    ~B();

    static A* a;
};

A* B::a; // HERE

A::A()
{
    B::a = this; // and there was an error here too
}
```

Don't forget to define the other ctors/dtors.

Comment: I think what you mean is definition, not declaration.